# Proposal for New Site Name

Tags: discussion, site-improvement, private-beta

A previous discussion was on the ["Nutrition"](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/does-nutrition-really-deserve-top-billing-on-this-site) portion of this site and how questions may not necessarily be about sports nutrition, not that specificity is necessary to me.

There are some questions that aren't really fitness **or** nutrition like
[Choosing a Chair for Good Posture](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/769/choosing-a-chair-for-good-posture) which is more of a "well-being" kind of question. Perhaps we could reconsider the site name to be "Fitness and Well-Being" to be more encompassing to the interests/questions that are being asked?

Thoughts?

Comment: If this makes the scope way too broad because then I can see people asking questions about cancer, diseases, etc... then the chair question above should be closed like the [Recipe Question](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-on-recipes-aceptable) was

Answer (score 3):

Our current **FAQ** reads:

> Fitness and Nutrition - Stack Exchange is for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing health-related needs. Topics include exercise and training, nutrition and diets, wellness, and activities related to strength, endurance, agility, and cardiovascular fitness.

I have a feeling that the Fitness part of our current title makes it look like we're focused on weightlifting or exercising in a gym, rather than being about anything related to being or becoming fit. This might be because at least in Dutch, Fitness is synonymous for working out in a gym, if this extends to other languages the word *Fitness* in itself would be somewhat inappropriate.

I've already voiced my concerns regarding the Nutrition part of the site, but after discussing it with Robert I understand why to try and keep the sites scope broader rather than narrow. However, by having Nutrition explicitly in the title, I do think it gets more attention than would perhaps be appropriate.

[As I raised earlier on Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/merge-sports-proposals) I would much rather see this site transformed into a site that's about all forms of sports & exercise and everything related to being physically fit. I would propose that the site should be called **Fitness & Sports** and be a merger of all the Sports proposals on Area51.

<sub>The idea for this new title comes from Grace Note</sub>

Comment: Agreed, it would be good to have more consistency on which questions are getting closed so posters aren't confused. 

Is the site name changing to add "Physical Fitness"?

Comment: Well this isn't a decision for me to take @Rhea and I meant for the title to be 'only' Physical Fitness

Comment: There does to be an emphasis on weight lifting or training in a gym on the site. That seems to be the typical idea of "fitness" people think of "working out" as opposed to "playing a sport" which is also exercise. I myself am interested in things like hiking and gymnastics and snowboarding, but I also regularly practice kung fu and tai chi. By the definition of "physical fitness" you provided, does that mean you also want to attract more varieties of the types of fitness that people can do?

Comment: Definitely @Matt Chan, I would rather want us to be the Stack Overflow of Fitness, than to focus on small subset like weightlifting or running. I also believe that with our current set of 'hardcore' users we have quite good diversity to have a lot of topics covered. The rest will have to come through natural expansion.