# Is this nutrition (not fitness) question on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, migration

I'm deciding whether to migrate this question from Seasoned Advice or just close it as off-topic:

[What is responsible for the recent (last 5-10 years) increase in attention to gluten-free foods?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15745/41)

It's not a poorly-written question, and this is probably the *closest* site for it, but it might not be close *enough*.  [I know that you guys are not crazy about nutrition questions](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/1324) - frankly, neither am I - but it is in the site's title and I thought it might be better to ask.

Regardless of the answer, I'd also like people's thoughts on whether or not we should be migrating nutrition questions in general (assuming that they aren't total crap, but don't relate to fitness either).  Is the F&N community interested or not really?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an interesting question that I've had myself, and it seems perfectly on-topic here. This site, per title, FAQ, and questions is as much about nutrition as it is about exercises ("fitness").

I don't think that the linked meta post (in OP) was in any way conclusive that nutrition was off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any question asked on a *Cooking* site would be on-topic for Nutrition. Instead of focusing on what the food does the body, the questions are more likely to focus on the food itself.

Just as a lot of questions we get about "Is X healthy for you?" doesn't focus on what the supposed effects of some ingredient of X is on your body and whether or not that's harmful. Instead they seem to look for confirmation on whether they can drink tons of Red Bull. Perhaps they like to debunk myths on Skeptics, but I'd prefer if users asked **real** questions.

So if it were up to me, I would rather not have these questions migrated, because I think they would make a poor fit to our site.