# Are questions specifically about nutrition on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I joined this site because it says "Fitness and nutrition" and I care about the nutrition aspect. Specifically - I am going to play with the paleo diet.

Unfortunately, this SE seems to be about Fitness, not Nutrition. Whoops. Is it about both? The mods seem to think it is about only Fitness.

Comment: The mods also gave plenty of reasons why they seem to think this, perhaps you should have a look at those ;-)

Comment: I started writing a longer answer, but it wasn't necessary. Here are the links I gathered up: [1](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/137), [2](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/49), [3](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/296), [4](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/171), [5](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/186), [6](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/287), [7](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/234)

Comment: This is apparently the eighth great sign that we should make true in name what is already true in fact. Fitness.SE, not F&N.SE.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I'll just be sad not to have a place where I can ask my questions -- even more so because the people on this SE seem to actually know the answers!

Comment: @Trevoke PaleoHacks is a SE site (using version 1.0), and it is much more active than this site. Go there, check out Robb Wolf's stuff, Mark Sisson, and Loren Cordain, and you will find out everything you could want to know about eating Paleo.

Comment: @michael oh nice! Thanks!

Comment: @MattChan or any other moderator - how can we finally put this name change to bed? We're still kicking our users in the face. Just one of the latest examples: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/eat-raw-egg-yolk-without-boiling-or-cooking

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: Also there is a [health SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2) that is in commitment phase, which hopefully will include nutrition.

Answer (score 5):

The [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) states that "nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc." is off-topic. If you do write your question about nutrition such that it is related to exercise, then it would be on-topic.

At the current moment, there isn't any place where you can ask general nutrition questions. Historically, the site was getting questions that fell more along the lines of "[general health and wellness](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/where-does-fitness-stop-and-general-health-start)" without necessarily relating to (physical) fitness. The problem with those questions was that people were, in a way, asking for [validation of their choices](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/241). We also have the problem of not having a good base (if any) of nutrition experts who could answer those questions.

The discussion of the site's [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) has come up numerous times in the past. As a result, the consensus was to focus the site on physical fitness and have nutrition be a secondary component of that.

Comment: Another issue is the legality of offering nutrition advice if you aren't certified... the site could get in trouble...

Comment: @NathanWheeler: we have lots of federal guidance for nutrition.  The legality of offering fitness advice - which is arguably more dangerous - seems *at least* as questionable.

Answer (score 3):

There are examples of questions around diets, even specifically the paleo diet already on the site. Nutrition questions that are considered off-topic is summed up in this section from the [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Fitness - Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes,
>   trainers and enthusiasts. If you have a question about …
>
> - improving your exercise performance or technique
> - choosing a training program
> - nutrition as it relates to exercise
> - gear and gadgets used during exercise
> - achieving physique milestones
> - injury prevention
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - the rules of a sport
> - a purchase recommendation
> - nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc.
> - trainer certification -- it’s for professionals, but not about the profession
> - wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!